# AADSTS50001: is not registered for the account

Tags: azure

I am receiving this error "AADSTS50001: is not registered for the account." when I log into my web app hosted in Azure Cloud. I am trying to log in using a different domain then the address my web app is linked too.

I added the e-mail address that I am trying to login with to the AAD of the domain name of the web app that I am accessing. I still got the error message.

Here is the full error message.

Additional technical information:
Correlation ID: 3411f3dd-a2c8-4412-9534-4d18123601bc
Timestamp: 2014-08-26 13:30:55Z
AADSTS50001: is not registered for the account.

Comment: How is your app configured to do authentication?  When you mention 'ADD' do you mean Azure Active Directory (AAD)?

Comment: Yes I mean AAD,  auto correct kept on changing it.  I configured it for a multi tenant application.  I can log in with my Microsoft account and the email associated with the domain.  However when I added another user to the active directory who is already in another active directory that is when I get the error message.